# Excel Import : Data not being read if column has different data formats in MVC C# using linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, excel-import

I am importing an excel sheet through a mvc website using linq statement as below

```
var  members = (from memRec in excelFile.Worksheet(sheetName)
                where memRec["FIRST_NAME"] != null 
                select memRec).ToList();
foreach (var member in members)
{
//save data
}
```

The problem here is let say a particular column "Date Of Birth" for first 2 columns the cell format is  `"DATE" and display as dd/MM/yyyy` and 3rd column the cell format is `"Text" and display as dd/MM/yyyy` the excel will consider it as no value there for 3rd column because of format mismatch.

Is there any way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try declare object and use predefined data types, Like:

```
var q = from memRec in excelFile.Worksheet(sheetName)
        where memRec["FIRST_NAME"] != null 
        select new Person()
        {
            Date = (DateTime)memRec [“Date”],
            FirstName= (string)memRec [“FirstName”],
            Age= (int)memRec [“Age”],
        };
```

Comment: will it import all rows from the sheet to q?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

In our server it is Office 2010.

Change the registry entry as below

1. In Windows environments, select Start ► Run and type REGEDIT to display
   the Registry Editor.
2. In the registry tree, select HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE ► Software ► Microsoft ►
   Office ► 12.0 ► Access Connectivity Engine ► Engines.
3. Double-click the Excel node.
4. In the right panel, double-click the TypeGuessRows entry.
5. Change the value data from 8 to 0.
6. Click OK.
7. Select File ► Exit to exit the Registry Editor window.

Now the excel wont guess the row datatype since we changed the value from 8 to 0.